# Can we add image in code comments in VS code

Tags: angular, typescript, comments, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to add an image in code comments in VS code? I am working on an angular project. Adding meaningful comments is an important step in the project. Explaining a login in comments in natural language is not effective, however adding an image would help a lot. Is there a way we can add an Image is code comments either directly or thru 3rd party extensions. Please look at the image below. I want the actual image to be visible in the comments rather than a link or a path.

[image: standard png screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension for this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgiesen.image-comments

Usage:

```
// Describes the function logic [image-comments/image1.png]
```

The only way to display an image is to hover over the comment, as it is not possible to place images directly in the code, since it is implemented as a textarea.

Comment: I tried above extension, but it is not working. As a matter of fact, the image above shows that i have placed the image reference in square brackets, but it doesn't work as explained in the extension. I tried to give absolute path, relative path, placed the image in a different folder, but nothing worked.

Comment: As far as I can tell this extension only recognizes single line comments in javascript.